# Erro HttpRequest php

Tags: php, json, libcurl, sms

Não consigo usar o script por causa da class HttpRequest já baixei várias classes e sempre da erro:
(https://dev.infobip.com/docs/fully-featured-textual-message)

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/advanced');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'accept' => 'application/json',
  'authorization' => 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==',
  'content-type' => 'application/json'
));

$request->setBody('{
   "bulkId":"BULK-ID-123-xyz",
   "messages":[
      {
         "from":"InfoSMS",
         "destinations":[
            {
               "to":"41793026727",
               "messageId":"MESSAGE-ID-123-xyz"
            },
            {
               "to":"41793026731"
            }
         ],
         "text":"Artık Ulusal Dil Tanımlayıcısı ile Türkçe karakterli smslerinizi rahatlıkla iletebilirsiniz.",
         "flash":false,
         "language":{
            "languageCode":"TR"
         },
         "transliteration":"TURKISH",
         "notifyUrl":"http://www.example.com/sms/advanced",
         "notifyContentType":"application/json",
         "callbackData":"DLR callback data",
         "validityPeriod": 720
      },
      {
         "from":"41793026700",
         "destinations":[
            {
               "to":"41793026785"
            }
         ],
         "text":"A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away... It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire.",
         "sendAt":"2015-07-07T17:00:00.000+01:00"
      }
   ]
}');

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

Então deu Tudo certo obrigado pelo Ajuda MIGUEL o código certo ficou:

```
    <?php
$data_string = '{
                           "messages":[
                              {
                                 "from":"InfoSMS",
                                 "destinations":[
                                    {
                                       "to":"5517998652984"
                                    }
                                 ],
                                 "text":"O SMS chegou!",
                                 "flash":true
                              }
                            ]
                        }';


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/advanced",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "authorization: Basic QnbcXX6735BYH==",
    "content-type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá?

Comment: Class Https No Found

Comment: Qual o URL da API, aquele que envia a sms, é isso que pretende certo? Enviar uma sms?

Comment: isso enviar sms a url é:

Comment: http://api.infobip.com/tts/3/single

Comment: Tentou com o exemplo deles? no final desta página https://dev.infobip.com/docs/send-single-sms, em baixo onde diz "https://dev.infobip.com/docs/send-single-sms", na parte request tem lá uma tab que tem um exemplo de php

Comment: tentei mas também usa a class httpsrequest ai da erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente o seguinte, fazendo com curl:

```
$headers = array(
  'accept' => 'application/json',
  'content-type' => 'application/json',
  'authorization' => 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=='
);
$data_string = '{
   "bulkId":"BULK-ID-123-xyz",
   "messages":[
      {
         "from":"InfoSMS",
         "destinations":[
            {
               "to":"41793026727",
               "messageId":"MESSAGE-ID-123-xyz"
            },
            {
               "to":"41793026731"
            }
         ],
         "text":"Artık Ulusal Dil Tanımlayıcısı ile Türkçe karakterli smslerinizi rahatlıkla iletebilirsiniz.",
         "flash":false,
         "language":{
            "languageCode":"TR"
         },
         "transliteration":"TURKISH",
         "notifyUrl":"http://www.example.com/sms/advanced",
         "notifyContentType":"application/json",
         "callbackData":"DLR callback data",
         "validityPeriod": 720
      },
      {
         "from":"41793026700",
         "destinations":[
            {
               "to":"41793026785"
            }
         ],
         "text":"A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away... It is a period of civil war. Rebel spaceships, striking from a hidden base, have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire.",
         "sendAt":"2015-07-07T17:00:00.000+01:00"
      }
   ]
}';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.infobip.com/sms/1/text/single');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $return;
```

Comment: deu alguns erro no meu PHP ai to arrumando e testando aqui

Comment: não mostra nada executei o código só que não faz nada

Comment: sim fiz acho que o curl não ta dando o tempo pro site responder

Comment: pq no javascript demora uns 10 segundos pra mostrar a no LOG que a mensagem foi enviada

Comment: obrigado, vou tentar

Comment: colouqei o set_time_limit(0) e nada o script abre normal só que não aparece nada o site fica em branco nem erro nada. será que é o CURLOPT_USERAGENT que ta como mozila o meu é chrome? tem algo a ver

Comment: não, também estou estranhado não faz exatamente nada

Comment: achei na infobip ese link:https://dev.infobip.com/docs/single-voice-message e tem em CURL só que pra outro tipo de SMS ai tentei adaptar mas deu erro

Comment: vou tentar mandar pro meu servidor ve se da umas resposta diferente

Comment: agora consegui recebi o mesmo erro que na imagem que vc enviou, mas não era pra dar erro pq coloquei a key da API

Comment: achei na infobip ese link:dev.infobip.com/docs/single-voice-message e tem em CURL só que pra outro tipo de SMS ai tentei adaptar mas deu erro

Comment: ae vc foi de mais de mais memso me ajudou bastante consegui unir o código da infobip com o seu e funcionou to 1 semana já tentando e consegui VLW mesmo o código ficou assim:

Comment: desculpa, primeira vez que entro nesse site e não achei nada pra dar aceite